# problem with passing variables (php, sql, jquery draggable)

Tags: javascript, sql, draggable

problem with passing variables (php, sql, jquery draggable)

Hi,

this is my problem: updating sql via jquery draggable.

I have two columns in a page populated by sql. drag and drop from one column to another works.  My problem, i have problem passing the row id into droppable for sql update.  Can you help?

this is the html:

```
<div class="result_box1">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <div>
        <span>Job Number</span>
        <span>Manager</span>
      <?php do { ?>
        <div class="draggable data_row" >
          <span><?php echo $row_diag['job_number']; ?></span>
          <span><?php echo $row_diag['manager_label']; ?></span>
        </div>
        <?php } while ($row_diag = mysql_fetch_assoc($diag)); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and here's the javascript:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".draggable").draggable();
    $(".droppable").droppable({
        drop: function() {update_sql(); }
    });
  });
```

Comment: As an aside: you're using a do..while loop, won't that make $row_diag be an uninitialised variable on the first iteration of the loop? Also, why not use <table> for what looks a damn lot like a table of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very clear on what the "problem" is. Assuming you don't know what approach to use to begin with: you could store the row id as a [data attribute](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) on the data_row div. So the PHP to output the row would be:

```
<div class="draggable data_row" data-rowid="<?= $row_diag['rowid'] ?>">
    <span><?php echo $row_diag['job_number']; ?></span>
    <span><?php echo $row_diag['manager_label']; ?></span>
</div>
```

If you're using jQuery already, you can retrieve the value using the [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data) method:

```
$(".droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(evt, ui) {
        var droppedRowid = ui.draggable.data('rowid');
        update_sql(droppedRowid); 
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot.  I had to add echo on the data-rowid value.  This works perfectly.  many thanks again.

Comment: @Riza The echo shorthand is probably turned off on your PHP deployment. (Or I got the syntax wrong, `<?= $foo ?>` should be equivalent to `<?php echo $foo; ?>`)